# Choosing a GoF Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

We currently undertaking a mass conversion of Access apps to .NET front-ends.  A lot of the Access Apps have reports and the method of creating a RDLC (or Crystal rpt), and a host form with dataset filling and binding is laborious.

So I'm creating a C# class library to help, you give it the report name, and it does the rest.
i.e. currently I can do:

```
   ReportViewer.GetReportViewer("ReportXXX")
      .AddParameter("UserID", "a983157")
      .SetFormSize(new Size(1024, 768))
      .SetFormTitle("My Report")
      .SetFormLocation(FormStartPosition.CenterScreen)
      .Show();
```

This works for the built in RDLC format, but I'm looking to expand it to Crystal.  But I know that if I just add it to the same class library then I'll need to distribute both the Microsoft Reporting assemblies and the Crystal ones.

So I was looking to split it into 3, one lib for the common code, and then one for the Microsoft and one for Crystal.  The consumers won't be expanding or adding their own, they just pass me a report name, and I work out what type it is and build the appropriate form.

I think its a Builder Pattern I want, but not sure, Bridge also seems suitable but its not a constructional one, which I *think* is what I'll be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you actually want a [Factory design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).  The common code would be put in a base class and you would have two derived classes from the base class, one for Crystal and one for RDLC.  The Factory would return the appropriate object instance for reporting dependent on the report name.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a tip, you need to understand that no rule says you must be stuck on a single pattern. Actually, no single design patterns in practical sense is used alone.